# How can I reduce a numpy array based on a key rather than an axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, key, reduce

I have a numpy array with 2 columns.  The second column represents the keys that I want to reduce on.

```
>>> x
array([[0.1 , 1.  ],
       [0.25, 1.  ],
       [0.45, 0.  ],
       [0.55, 0.  ]])
```

I want to sum up all the values which share a key, like this.

```
>>>sum_key(x)
array([[0.35 , 1.  ],
       [1.0, 0.  ]])
```

This seems like a relatively universal task, but I can't find a good name for it or see it discussed.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda overcomplicated but it should do the work:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0.1 , 1.  ],
       [0.25, 1.  ],
       [0.45, 0.  ],
       [0.55, 0.  ]])
keys = x[:,1]
values = x[:,0]
keys_unique = np.unique(keys)
print([[sum(values[keys == k]), k] for k in keys_unique])
```

Output:

```
[[1.0, 0.0], [0.35, 1.0]]
```

Comment: Great! this seems to work.  I'm interested using this for somewhat large arrays O(10^6) elements. So hopefully it scales reasonably

Answer (score 1):

If the indices (keys) are ascending integers (or can be casted easily as in your case) the most convenient way is to use
[np.bincount](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html).

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0.1 , 1.  ],
             [0.25, 1.  ],
             [0.45, 0.  ],
             [0.55, 0.  ]])

v = x[:, 0]
i = x[:, 1]

counts = np.bincount(i.astype(int), v)

print(counts)

# returns [1.   0.35]
```

Comment: The keys are integers, but may be negative as well.  This solution works, but will require a little extra gymnastics to keep track of the correspondence with the keys

Comment: Yes, but it is probably faster than other approaches. You need to check, maybe it is worth the little extra gymnastics.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without numpy.

Grouping elements by key is typically done with a python dict.

Be careful if your keys are floating-points. For instance, 1.000000001 and 1.0 will be distinct keys. I suggest rounding to int first.

### Using a dict

```py
x = [[0.1 , 1  ],
     [0.25, 1  ],
     [0.45, 0  ],
     [0.55, 0  ]]

y = {}
for v, k in x:
    y[k] = y.get(k, 0) + v

print(y)
{1: 0.35, 0: 1.0}
```

You can get an array again from dict `y` if you want:

```py
z = np.array([(v,k) for k,v in y.items()])

print(z)
# [[0.35 1.  ]
#  [1.   0.  ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([[0.1 , 1.  ],
       [0.25, 1.  ],
       [0.45, 0.  ],
       [0.55, 0.  ]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

gr = df.groupby([1])[0].agg('sum')

print(gr.keys().values)

data1 = np.array([[gr[k],k] for k in gr.keys().values])
print(data1)
```

Comment: This solution is a bit complicated and introduces an unnecessary dependence on pandas.  Is there any advantage over ExplodingGayFish's answer?