# pytorch: efficient way to perform operations on 2 tensors of different sizes, where one has a one-to-many relation

Tags: algorithm, pytorch, one-to-many

I have 2 tensors. The first tensor is 1D (e.g. a tensor of 3 values). The second tensor is 2D, with the first dim as the IDs to first tensor in a one-many relationship (e.g. a tensor with a shape of 6, 2)

```
# e.g. simple example of dot product
import torch

a = torch.tensor([2, 4, 3])
b = torch.tensor([[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 1], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 1]]) # 1st column is the index to tensor a, 2nd column is the value

output = [(2*2)+(2*3)+(2*1),(4*4),(3*3)+(3*1)]
output = [12, 16, 12]
```

Current what I have is to find the size of each id in b (e.g. [3,1,2]) then using torch.split to group them into a list of tensors and running a for loop through the groups. It is fine for a small tensor, but when the size of the tensors are in millions, with tens of thousands of arbitrary-sized groups, it became very slow.

Any better solutions?

Comment: Maybe `a[b[:,0]].dot(b[:, 1])` or `a[b[:,0]] * b[:, 1]`?

Comment: See also this question which looks extremely relevant: [How can I reduce a numpy array based on a key rather than an axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759852/how-can-i-reduce-a-numpy-array-based-on-a-key-rather-than-an-axis)

Comment: Following the question I linked, maybe `np.bincount(b[:,0], b[:,1])` or `np.bincount(b[:,0], b[:,1]) * a` which returns `[12., 16., 12.]`.

Comment: Hi you assumed correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.bincount` or `torch.bincount` to sum the elements of `b` by key:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,4,3])
b = np.array([[0,2], [0,3], [0,1], [1,4], [2,3], [2,1]])

print( np.bincount(b[:,0], b[:,1]) )
# [6. 4. 4.]

print( a * np.bincount(b[:,0], b[:,1]) )
# [12. 16. 12.]
```

```py
import torch

a = torch.tensor([2,4,3])
b = torch.tensor([[0,2], [0,3], [0,1], [1,4], [2,3], [2,1]])

torch.bincount(b[:,0], b[:,1])
# tensor([6., 4., 4.], dtype=torch.float64)

a * torch.bincount(b[:,0], b[:,1])
# tensor([12., 16., 12.], dtype=torch.float64)
```

References:

- [numpy.bincount official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html);
- [torch.bincount official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bincount.html);
- [How can I reduce a numpy array based on a key rather than an axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759852/how-can-i-reduce-a-numpy-array-based-on-a-key-rather-than-an-axis)

Comment: Thanks! it worked. However, I was using it as part of a loss calculation, which required it to have gradient. In pytorch 1.13, torch.bincount gave an error. Although I found that torch.scatter_add or torch.index_add did the same. :)

Comment: I must have been blindsided when I read your question yesterday, I didn't even realise you were asking about torch and not numpy. Some days I read what I want to read rather than what's written! What was the error given by torch.bincount?

Comment: Looks like it works for me: `a = torch.tensor([2,4,3]); b = torch.tensor([[0,2], [0,3], [0,1], [1,4], [2,3], [2,1]]); ` `torch.bincount(b[:,0], b[:,1])` gives
`tensor([6., 4., 4.], dtype=torch.float64)`; and `a * torch.bincount(b[:,0], b[:,1])` gives `tensor([12., 16., 12.], dtype=torch.float64)`

Comment: It was this error. RuntimeError: derivative for bincount is not implemented. It happens when you use it as a loss function calculation.

Comment: @ChienPoon Ah. I see that [the documentation for torch.bincount](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bincount.html) says: *"This operation may produce nondeterministic gradients when given tensors on a CUDA device. See [Reproducibility](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) for more information."*

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative in pytorch if gradient is needed.

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([2,4,3])
b = torch.tensor([[0,2], [0,3], [0,1], [1,4], [2,3], [2,1]])

output = torch.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype=torch.long).index_add_(0, b[:, 0], b[:, 1]) * a
```

alternatively, torch.tensor.scatter_add also works.